# Is the word "snob" a formal or informal word?

Tags: word-meaning

Is the word "snob" a formal or informal word ? I need to know how to use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairly informal. Normally pejorative. It is an insult.

It can be combined quite freely to form compounds like "wine-snob" (someone who considers cheap or ordinary wine to be substandard)  Again normally pejorative (they judge a wine by its price, not by its taste)

Like many insults, it may be used in banter and self-deprecatingly

It is part of the "nice to have, but not essential" part of English. I would expect native speakers to understand the word. I would not be surprised if non-native speakers did not know the word.

Comment: I guess by "fairly informal" you mean it's a general-usage word that's neither formal nor informal.  I'd certainly be happy to use it in everyday speech and when writing a book, so I'd agree that (like most of the words in this comment!) it doesn't have a particular register that affects where you could use it.

Comment: Regarding formality, it's middling, particular to a social class in informal situations. You wouldn't use it in very formal documents (although it's probably fine e.g. in literary criticism or political speeches it's not a neutral descriptor and wouldn't be used in writing that aims to be scientific or balanced). But equally you wouldn't expect to hear it often in a rap song, and young working class kids will have other, more colorful ways of accusing people of being snobbish. It's a middle-class insult.

Comment: I don't think there is a connotation of "judge a wine by its price". It *is* pejorative, however. I would say the implications of being a "wine snob" would be unreasonably high standards and contempt for anything they consider not to meet them, but they may well be genuinely expert. If they didn't actually know about wine and used price as a proxy for quality, I think a more accurate term would be "wannabe wine snob".

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  I'd tend to disagree.  A genuine expert is one thing. But to describe someone as a snob is pejorative.   Wine snobs will turn their nose up at a good wine because it doesn't come from the "right" country or or year, or have the right  name. That is they are not truly experts in wine. I true expert would recognise a  quality wine even if it didn't have the right "branding".

Comment: I had a colleague who was extremely fussy about having the right kind of glass for the right kind of wine. I would describe him as a wine snob not because he didn't know what he was talking about, but because he was excessively fussy and particular about details that most people would consider unimportant. Pejorative in the sense of lacking a sense of proportion, not in terms of being ignorant.

Comment: @JamesK I'm sure many experts are not snobs and would be perfectly happy with reasonably good wine on a normal occasion.  For me a snob is someone for whom reasonably good is not good enough, whether or not their assessment of what's good is reliable. I do not know enough myself to tell who is a genuine expert and who is bluffing, but I can tell whether they are (by my definition) snobbish about it.